# Проблема перехода между сценами. Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие меры можно предпринять, если при переходе из одной сцены в другую. Сцена, на которую я перехожу, затемняется. Я знаю такой прикол(баг) в редакторе Unity. В интернете пишут, что в сбилденном проекте такое исчезает. Но у меня это не исчезает даже в сбилденном проекте. Мне особо нет никакой разницы на редактор, но вот в сбилденном проекте обидно, что этот баг не исчезает. Что можно с этим сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста. По поводу света: на сцене простой Direction Light, в настройках Lightning: None(Lightning Settings) - не вижу смысла там что-то менять, так как идет нагрузка на игру.

Answer (score 1):

Это из - за твоей версии Unity

Скачай новую

Это просто баг версии

Или создай новый проект и помести всё туда из старого проекта

А старый проект удали

Типо проблемы с железом

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).